# MySQL FullText search - a boolean search term under the min token size means no results come back

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I have a table of school data with fulltext indexes on the columns, in Mysql 5.6.33.

The `innodb_ft_min_token_size` is set to 3 (the default).  This is the smallest word that gets indexed.

If I **search** for a postcode, where one of the parts is less than this size, then the search gives a score of 0 to the record with that postcode:

```
mysql> SELECT record_id, keywords, 
    -> MATCH (keywords) AGAINST ("+l4 +0uf" IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
    -> FROM squirrel_schools 
    -> WHERE record_id = 137212;
+-----------+---------------------+-------+
| record_id | keywords            | score |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+
|    137212 | l4 0uf l40uf 137212 |     0 |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, we can see that it does have both of the required words in the keywords field, but is given a score of 0.

This seems to be because of the `innodb_ft_min_token_size` variable, because if I change the postcode and search term to "L4X 0UF" instead then it works fine.  So it's having a two-letter word in there that's breaking it.

Now, I would understand if it would **ignore** the "+L4" bit because it's less that the min token size: for example, if it ignored the "+L4", and just gave a score to that record based on matching "+0UF", then that would at least seem consistent with the purpose of having a min token size.

But to let it break the search so it doesn't give a score to something with that word in it seems really wrong.

Can someone explain if I'm doing something wrong here, or if I've misunderstood how min token size is supposed to work?

EDIT - I understand that I can change the `innodb_ft_min_token_size` variable, eg to 2 instead of 3, and that might solve this particular search.  But I'd like to understand the actual logic behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM would get you the row, but InnoDB says:

"You demanded (via the `+`) that `14` be included, but since I did not index it, I did not find it.  So the row is excluded."

It is debatable whether that is "right" but that is what it does.

The workaround I use is to not put a `+` in front of any strings that are too short.  If I really want to force `14` to exist, then I add something like

```
AND col REGEXP "[[:<:]]14[[:>:]]"
```

It will do the `MATCH` first (faster), then double check with the `REGEXP`.

The funny bracket thingies are "word boundaries".  So it matches when the `14` occurs as a "word" anywhere inside `col`.  It won't match, for example `146` but it will match `Address: 14 Main st.` or plain `14`.

Comment: Thanks, that was my suspicion.  It's definitely a bug, I would say, or a bit of bad design at least.  IMO the caller of the search shouldn't have to know which words are indexed and which are not.  If a word is ignored for indexing it should be ignored for searching - that seems like the common sense rule, at least.

Comment: I just read the regex bit - would you mind expanding your answer to just add a note about what's going on with that regex?  I don't understand that syntax at all.  thanks!

Comment: @MaxWilliams - feel free to write a bug report at bugs.mysql.com ; I'll upvote it.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - added a brief note about the regexp